# How to force an <img> to take up width, even if the image is not loaded

Tags: html, css, image, sizing

I'm loading a bunch of img's, and I'd like them to take up space on the document even if they are not loaded, or have not completed loading yet.

I tried specifying width and height (both as attributes themselves, and within a style attribute), and find it frustrating that the images will not take up space if they don't load.

**Surely, there must be a way to force an img to specific dimensions, **even if that image fails to load.**

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There certainly is:

```
<img src="path/to/image.png" height="50" width="20" />
```

Also, the reason specifying the width and height within the `style="/* css */"` attribute didn't work is because images are, by default, in-line elements. Had you specified `display: block` the image would've accepted the `width` and `height` values.

If you add, to the css/style:

```
display: inline-block;
```

It should work. I'm not sure *why* Firefox doesn't respect the width/height attributes, but still. Even IE, with a defined `doctype` should respect `display: inline-block`, since `img` elements are, by default, in-line anyway.

Comment: @Andrew Vit, thanks for the edit. I accidentally un-did it while I was adding information at the same time as you performed your edit. The revocation was accidental, and an oversight. Edited your edit back in, where it belongs! =)

Comment: This doesn't work if the image does not load.  At least, in latest FF on Windows.

Comment: @Sambo, nor in Firefox 3.6.10 on Ubuntu 10.04. See edit, and [jsbin demo](http://jsbin.com/ojocu3/3/), it should work now.

Comment: @David How to define DOCTYPE in IE to respect `display: inline-block`? Thanks.

Comment: It's been a while since I worked with IE, but have a look at: [Doctype.com](http://doctype.com/doctype-should-use), or [htmlhelp.com](http://htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/doctype.html) for ideas. It mostly depends on your usage, but I'd personally recommend `<!DOCTYPE html>` now, but otherwise html or xhtml strict are both good.

Comment: display: inline-block; works beautifully.  Thanks for the help, David.

Comment: @Sambo, also, if that's solved your problem, I wouldn't be *offended* if you decided to accept the answer =b

Comment: I accepted this as the answer.  I hope, as promised, you will not be offended.  :)

Comment: @Sambo, ha! You, sir, are a star. Many thanks for the accept =)

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer: wrap the image in a `<div>` with a fixed width.

```
<div style="width: 400px;"><img src="404.png" /></div>
```

If you set padding, border etc to `0`, you won't notice that the div is there.

Comment: So why put it there? The `div` will shrink-to-fit around the image *unless* it (the `div`) is set to `display: block` or `inline-block`. So you'd be as well off just specifying `display: block;` (or `inline-block`) on the `img`, plus `img` accepts `width` and `height` attributes for a reason.

Comment: No, the `div` will *not* shrink to fit around the image - `display: block` is the default value for a `div`. On the other hand, specifying `display: block` on the image would probably work just as well. The problem with that is, that if you load a smaller image than the html specified dimensions, the image will be distorted.